# javascript defer keyword not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, html

As far as I know, if we set **defer** keyword on a script tag it will not block the rest of the page to render, the rest of the page will be rendered and just before the window load event the script tag will be executed.

I have a simple HTML and which has a script tag with a defer attribute. Inside the script tag, I have a long loop so that it will take time, and below this script tag, I have a paragraph tag as well. Ideally, when I will reload the browser, my all the content should be rendered and then script execution should be there, but the last paragraph is not being rendered earlier as expected.

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hi I am a p tag</p>
    <img src="./img/Screenshot 2020-07-25 at 11.50.51 PM.png" />
    <input type="text" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./src/file1.js" defer></script>
    <p>I will be rendered earlier as above javascript file has a defer attribute</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you create an online example for it?

Comment: Try putting the script tag after <p>

Answer (score 2):

The script isn't the problem here. It is your `link` tag causing the issue.

You can see this demo here;

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_script_defer

If you add this line within the body;

`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://source.zoom.us/1.7.10/css/bootstrap.css" />`

Watch how the `p` tags now render after the alert.

Comment: But why that will cause the issue. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Also, I noticed one more thing, If I remove the link tag then <p> tag is rendered before but the image is rendered only after the script has been executed.

Comment: ``link`` tags, particularly ``stylesheets`` should be declared in the ``head`` tags. Things in the ``head`` tags will load before the rest of the body. Because you've put it in the body, it then has to load that stylesheet, but your script would have fired before then. Putting the CSS in the ``head`` will ensure that it is loaded BEFORE the body.

Comment: An ``image`` has to be served. It only appears that your image is rendered after the script runs because your script might be blocking the render (depending what your script does), so in the example of an alert - alerts obscure the rendering and makes it appear like the page hasn't loaded but it has, you will only see it AFTER the alert is closed.

Comment: Yeah but doesn't defer mean that it will execute the script only after the rest of the page is rendered?

Comment: A defered script will not run until after the page has loaded. That does not include images. It is in reference to when the DOM is ready. A DOM can be ready while images are downloading.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't the script tag, it's the link tag. It should be located inside of `<head>`, not on `<body>`.

Comment: This. The script isn't the problem. Your call to the CSS is causing this load issue.